# Laravel orderBy slowing down response

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent, sql-order-by

I am using Eloquent to fetch results from the database.

The table has a large number of rows (~1 million) and the response time is greatly increased when using `orderBy()`.

This is my query, just a simple search string match:

`Movie::selectRaw("id, title, poster")->whereRaw("MATCH(title) AGAINST('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")->orderBy('popularity', 'desc')->take(10)->get();`

Unfortunately, ordering by popularity is necessary because otherwise the first 10 results are almost always irrelevant.

In case this is helpful, I used to use `where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')` but then I changed my approach to `MATCH(title) AGAINST('$search')` which improves performance significantly, but sadly `orderBy()` kills that improvement.

Is there any way I could speed up this process or is there maybe a workaround so I could avoid `orderBy()` altogether?

Comment: Have you tried `orderByRaw()` ?

Comment: Do you mean replace ```orderBy()``` with ```orderByRaw()```? I just tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean by generated SQL. Do you mean the results the query returns? Or the query itself but instead of in eloquent format, in its SQL format?